# Haproxy - First health check after service startup vs inter param

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have in my haproxy.cfg a external-script check.

```
 external-check command /etc/haproxy/check_primary.sh
 server SERVER_NAME SERVER_IP:444 check inter 15m
 server SERVER_NAME SERVER_IP:444 check backup inter 15m
```

The external script works fine but as I set the inter parameter to 15 minutes, the first check after restarting the service happens after 15 minutes. I would expect the first check to occur just after haproxy starts and 15 minutes later the second check.
The reason I took 15 minutes is that the script makes an API call to an application and generates a lot of logs at the application level.

Is there a way to force haproxy to do the first check when it starts ?

Thx

I tried the passive check but without success

Comment: I answer my own question. ;-) 
Adding "fastinter 5s" does the trick